# I have an error "apt-get -f install", help me fix it

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, package-management

So in the last time I kinda' broke my Ubuntu server and I'm getting the following error, I want to say that I deleted some of the `libjpeg8:i386` things and now I can't install any packages!

```
root@s1:~# apt-get install php-apc 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
libgd3:i386 : Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed  
libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed  
libsane:i386 : Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed  
libtiff5:i386 : Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed  
libv4lconvert0:i386 : Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed  
php-apc : Depends: php5-apcu but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

root@s1:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg8:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjpeg8:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,188 B of archives.
After this operation, 26.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 247834 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg8:i386 (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libjpeg8/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libjpeg8:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Yes and I get this http://pastebin.com/r6SBsaG7 .

Comment: Something weird is going on with `libjpeg8`. Please edit your question to add the output of `dpkg -l | grep libjpeg8` and `apt-cache policy libjpeg8`.

Comment: This are the commands outputs: http://pastebin.com/267X5Kdz , http://pastebin.com/mNdCRPmE

Comment: I think that answer is bordering on `chmod 777` will make everything work fine...

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem, sorry for bothering you guys, thanks for all the support!

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/var/cache apt/archives/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_i386.deb
```

Check everything is fixed by running :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you still have problems rerun the first step with any dpkg: error processing (...) remaining